# iPhone XR take a second to go to sleep, instead of going out instantly

Tags: iphone, sleep-wake, software

I got my iPhone XR just days ago and just recently upgraded to IOS 14. Now, the problem I am facing is no way near crazy problematic. However, it is kinda concerning given it's a brand new phone. After updating to IOS 14, it seems like my iPhone is "taking its time" to go to sleep. Like initially, I'd press the power button and it would immediately go to sleep but now it actually takes a second to go out followed by the locking sound effect. I don't know if the problem is because of updating to IOS 14 or something else. I hope someone could help me figure this out.

Comment: Have you set up Apple Pay? Do you have Settings → Accessibility → Accessibility Shortcut turned on?

Comment: No, I have not set up apple pay. As for accessibility shortcuts...I am not sure. But lemme check.

Comment: @grg oh damn...I do have my accessibility shortcut turned on. I turned on magnifier the other day. Seemed like a cool feature so I turned it on. Well anyways, I just turned it off and now my phone goes to sleep instantly. IDK why this happened tho

Answer (score 1):

The side button won’t immediately sleep your phone if iOS is waiting for a potential second press of the button. Features which enable a second press of the side button and thus delay sleep are:

- Apple Pay, where double press of the side button opens the wallet to your cards.
- Accessibility Shortcut (Settings → Accessibility), where triple press of the side button toggles your selected shortcut or opens a menu of your selected options.

Disabling these features will ensure a single press of the side button can only mean sleeping the device, therefore iOS won’t wait for a potential second press.

Comment: I see thanks for the info. However, my iPhone is back to normal instant sleep with one press even tho...I use the double press of the side button for apple pay. I have tho disabled accessibility shortcuts which fixed the problem.